# jQuery - Infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, infinite

I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling on my page, how ever something has messed up, instead of triggering at the bottom of the page it's triggering  when I scroll back to the top. Does anyone know what could be triggering this?

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        alert("hello");
    }
});
```

I'm currently using the code above, which works in jsfiddle just fine. I also tried an alternative of -

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
```

Note: I'm using CodeIgniter (although im not sure this would cause the problem?)

If you'd like to take a look at what I mean you can check out the test page at http://carllawl.kwebserv.info/recent (just scroll down then back up to see what I mean)

Comment: Can you try adding this to your script then let us know what it says. chk_val=$(document).height() - $(window).height(); console.log("chk_val=",chk_val);

Comment: You will need firebug to see the result if you are using firefox.

Comment: (Using chrome) it always returns - chk_val= 0

Comment: Try this *infinite scroll* script ☞ https://github.com/yairEO/infinite

Answer (score 0):

**USE THIS**

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() <= $(document).height() - $(window).height() && $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
    yourfunctionhere()
  }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your code to which I received the same result as above!